# Is a "literal type" the same thing as a "literal"?

Tags: c++, types, language-lawyer, terminology, literals

I've read about "literals" a bit, which seem to be kind of fixed values in source code. On the other hand I've come across the term "literal type", which can be

> A type is a literal type if it is:
>
> - a scalar type; or
> - a reference type referring to a literal type; or
> - an array of literal type; or
> - a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties: - it has a trivial destructor,
> - every constructor call and full-expression in the brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (if any) is a constant expression (5.19),
> - it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move constructor, and
> - all of its non-static data members and base classes are of literal types.

According to the c11 standard. Now I'm confused, because my impression is that "type" describes a different quality than "literal".... hence the question:

"Literal" and "Literal Type" are two distinct things - right?

Comment: In Stroustrup "The C++ Programming Language, I found this definition: "A Class with a *constexpr* constructor is called a *literal type*."

Comment: Yes, "literal" and "literal type" are distinct things.  In the C++17 standard, there is a footnote (number 22) which says "The term “literal” generally designates, in this International Standard, those tokens that are called “constants” in ISO C.".   
According to a note in the same standard (below para 10.5.4) a literal type is a type "for which it might be possible to create an object within a constant expression".    Neither of these are normative/formal definitions, but I mention them as they may aid understanding.